# Google Cloud Function + BigQuery memory consumption

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have a goole cloud function that finds occurrences in BigQuery table.
The difficulty i'm facing is that this table has over 57m rows and weights about 600mb, request comes every 2-3 minutes so memory consumption is pretty big for this kind of operation.
Table is set to auto-update once a day.
My question is: is there any ways to reduce memory consumption by saving this table to some sort of RAM of this function? Or any other suggestions.
Thanks is advance!

```
def main(request):
    
    request_json = request.get_json()
    email =  request_json['email']
    BQ_CLIENT_DWH = bq.Client()   
    query = f"SELECT count(*) as cnt from `project.dataset.table` where email = '{email}'" 
    frame = BQ_CLIENT_DWH.query(query).result().to_dataframe()
        

    return  f'Cnt = {frame.squeeze()}'
```

Comment: You process nothing in the Cloud Functions memory, all the processing is done by BigQuery. I don't understand your challenge/issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.